# Table recursive lookup on itself

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table below.

I want to select all of the members of Group-D

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
where grp = "Group-D"
```

However, Group-D also contains Group-C along with User 5.  Group-C contains Group-A and Group-B.

So, the select should return:

```
User-1
User-2
User-3
User-4
User-5
Group-A
Group-B
Group-C
```

Obviously, without doing multiple lookups on itself, I will not get that output.

How can I make the select statement do a table lookup within itself like that?

| grp | member |
| --- | --- |
| Group-A | User-1 |
| Group-A | User-2 |
| Group-B | User-3 |
| Group-B | User-4 |
| Group-C | Group-A |
| Group-C | Group-B |
| Group-D | Group-C |
| Group-D | User-5 |
| Group-E | User-6 |

Comment: How can Group-D "contain" Group-C when it's specified in a single column?

Comment: What is the bottom table (with `grp` and `member` columns)? Is that your sample input data or your sample output data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following **recursive CTE** will traverse through the data to arrive at parent/child relationships:

```
declare @value as varchar(40)
set @value = 'Group-D'

;with CTE as (
        select 1 as lvl, @value as member, cast(null as varchar(40)) as parent
        union all                  
        select CTE.lvl + 1, t.member, t.grp
        from CTE
        inner join mytable as t on CTE.member = t.grp
        where lvl < 10 
        )
select
    lvl, member, parent
from CTE
order by lvl, member
```

**result**

```
+-----+---------+---------+
| lvl | member  | parent  |
+-----+---------+---------+
|   1 | Group-D |         |
|   2 | Group-C | Group-D |
|   2 | User-5  | Group-D |
|   3 | Group-A | Group-C |
|   3 | Group-B | Group-C |
|   4 | User-1  | Group-A |
|   4 | User-2  | Group-A |
|   4 | User-3  | Group-B |
|   4 | User-4  | Group-B |
+-----+---------+---------+
```

See this working at *[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e9736e1d386c23f61d08669c93cfbe3e)*

Note, I introduced "lvl" as a way to implement an "escape" from the recursion - "just in case"

Also, if you don't want to include the top level item in the result, use

```
select
    lvl, member, parent
from CTE
where parent IS NOT NULL
order by lvl, member
```

and you could commence lvl as zero instead of 1 in the CTE

Comment: Is there a way to show the top parent of every item (in this case Group-D) in a column as well instead of just the immediate parent?

Comment: If you used @value as shown in my query, you could just output that can be displayed as a column in the final result. see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1fc0f00bf774707c90d82c0cfd00caa1